# Need to solve python logical task

Tags: python, datetime

```
import datetime

class Element(object):
    name: str
    datetime: datetime.datetime
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = args[0]
        self.datetime = args[1]
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.datetime.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")
        
e = Element("Name 1", datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 5, 20, 20, 20))
e2 = Element("Name 1", datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 5, 20, 20, 23))
e3 = Element("Name 2", datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 5, 19, 11, 10))
e4 = Element("Name 3", datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 5, 10, 15, 10))
e5 = Element("Name 3", datetime.datetime(2022, 3, 5, 10, 15, 8))
e6 = Element("Name 4", datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 7, 12, 12, 8))
e7 = Element("Name 4", datetime.datetime(2022, 4, 7, 12, 12, 20))

array = [e, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7]
new_array = []
```

I need to generate a new array with this rule: there were no elements with the same name if they have a datetime difference of less than 5 seconds

Comment: Let's assume you have 3 elements with the same name, the same date and the times of (2,2,0), (2,2,4) and (2,2,8). Do you want (2,2,0) and (2,2,8) or only (2,2,4)?

Comment: if i have two elements with same names but have difference in time of less than 5 seconds i nees only one of it

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. What happens if there a more elements than two? Do you want to reduce them to the minimal possible number or just handle them in the order they appear? As you can see in my comment there a two possible results and both are valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps try using another class to determine and store arrays

```
from datetime import datetime


class Arrays:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = {}

    def push(self, node):
        if node.name in self.nodes:
            for item in self.nodes[node.name]:
                delta = node.time - item.time
                seconds = 3600*24*abs(delta.days) - delta.seconds if delta.days < 0 else delta.seconds

                if seconds >= 5:
                    self.nodes[node.name].append(node)
        else:
            self.nodes[node.name] = [node]

    def get_array(self):
        return [item for value in self.nodes.values() for item in value]


class Element(object):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = args[0]
        self.time = args[1]

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name + " " + self.time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S")



arr = Arrays()
for ele in [Element("Name 1", datetime(2022, 1, 5, 20, 20, 20)),
            Element("Name 1", datetime(2022, 1, 5, 20, 20, 23)),
            Element("Name 2", datetime(2022, 2, 5, 19, 11, 10)),
            Element("Name 3", datetime(2022, 3, 5, 10, 15, 10)),
            Element("Name 3", datetime(2022, 3, 5, 10, 15, 8)),
            Element("Name 4", datetime(2022, 4, 7, 12, 12, 8)),
            Element("Name 4", datetime(2022, 4, 7, 12, 12, 20))]:
    arr.push(ele)
print(arr.get_array())
```